# a slice usage in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I once saw the following code segment, and am not clear what it does really do?

```
d = np.mean(a[::b,:,c:-c], axis=2, keepdims=False)
```

In specifi, what `::b` means here?

Comment: From start to end for axis 0..skipping b elements and using only b"th" element

Answer (score 1):

'::b' means "skip by b elements", (e.g. if 'b' = 3, this will give every third element in the list).

"[Extended Slices](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)" is the category of what you are asking about. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Python use slicing to specify how to slice a sequence. You can specify where to start the slicing, and where to end. You can also specify the step. step also refer to as interval here.

```
Syntax : a[start:end:step]
```

Example :

```
y = np.arange(42).reshape(6,7)
y[0::2]
```

Here 0 is the lower limit and 2 is the interval.  The output will start at index 0 and keep going till the end with an interval of 2.  That means every second row.
This how our output will look like

```
Output:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]])
```